# Observe array and get changed value in ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Here's the component:

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
    columns: []

    _watchColumns: function () {
        // console.log(changedValue);
    }.observes('columns.@each.name')

    // other code
});
```

I'd like to get the changed value in `_watchColumns` method. Is it possible?

Comment: Maybe _watchColums: function(newVal) will return the new value? It's like this in Angular, no idea with Ember.

Comment: Yes, that would be the desired behavior for me, but it doesn't work like that.

Comment: Tried reading the docs but it doesn't really explain anything about it strangely enough.

Comment: Perhaps this will help you in some way: http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/object-model/observers/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible.  A workaround might be to use a component for each item.

My-Columns component

```
//my-columns.js
export default Ember.Component.extend({
    columns: null
});

//my-columns.hbs
{{#each columns as |column|}}
    {{my-column value=column}}
{{/each}}
```

My-Column component

```
//my-column.js
export default Ember.Component.extend({
    nameUpdated : Ember.computed('value.name', function() {
        console.log(this.get('value.name'));
    });
});
```

---

**Another tip:** never set a property to `[]` or `{}` in a component as it will be shared across all instances of the compoent (like a static property - unless you want this behaviour of course).  In your case the user will override it by passing in their own columns object but it is helpful to know anyway.  If you need an array in your component you can do this:

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
    myArray : null,
    init : function() {
        this._super.apply(this, arguments);
        this.set('myArray', []);
    }
});
```

Comment: Vote up for the tip :).